# Memcached server consolidation issue on Rails 2.3: unable to find server during initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I have a Ruby on Rails 2.3.10 application that has an API running on one server and the application on another. Due to the nature of the app, the API, and the typical user flow; I need to centralize our caching. Currently I have memcached (1.4.2) running on each server (Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS).

When I try moving to a centralized memcached server, I consistently get this error both in production and development:

```
Read error: #<RuntimeError: #<ActionController::Session::MemCacheStore:0x108cb5dc8> unable to find server during initialization.
```

My development.rb and production.rb configs look like this:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, 'XX.XX.XX.XXX:11211'
```

I already configured my iptables and opened up port 11211. I can also then telnet into that server from my local machine and the servers.

Everything runs fine using this

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store
```

as long as memcached is running on the localhost.

I've also tried this using the last version of the Dalli gem that supports Rails 2.3 and get the same error.

Any ideas? I've searched everywhere and it *looks* like I'm configured correctly, but obviously something is wrong here.

Comment: Have you checked whether your `/etc/memcached.conf` still has this line: `-l 127.0.0.1`. If so, comment it out.

Comment: Yes, just doubled checked and it's commented out. Good suggestion though. That was one of the initial issues I was able to resolve when I wasn't able to telnet in. Commenting that out allowed me to telnet in.